# Perl XML LibXML to replace a node with the other on xsd schema

Tags: xml, perl, xsd, libxml2

I have an XML Schema and I would like to replace the RootNode with the element found inside of the RootNode complex Type with.

For example, below expected result is to have the `<xs:element name="RootNode" ...>` replaced by `<xs:element name="real_node" type="RealNode"/>` and remove the whole node of `<xs:complexType name="RootNode">`.

XML Schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="RootNode" type="RootNode"/>

    <xs:complexType name="RootNode">
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="real_node" type="RealNode"/>
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="RealNode">
            <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">TestName</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Type" xml:lang="EN">TestType</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Elem2" type="Type2" minOccurs="1">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation source="Name3" xml:lang="EN">TestName3</xs:documentation>
                                    <xs:documentation source="Type3" xml:lang="EN">TestType3</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Elem4" type="Type4" maxOccurs="99" />
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Type2">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{9,9}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Type4">
            <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Name5" xml:lang="EN">TestName5</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Type5" xml:lang="EN">TestType5</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{7,9}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="real_node" type="RealNode"/>

    <xs:complexType name="RealNode">
            <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">TestName</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Type" xml:lang="EN">TestType</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Elem2" type="Type2" minOccurs="1">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation source="Name3" xml:lang="EN">TestName3</xs:documentation>
                                    <xs:documentation source="Type3" xml:lang="EN">TestType3</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Elem4" type="Type4" maxOccurs="99" />
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Type2">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{9,9}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Type4">
            <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Name5" xml:lang="EN">TestName5</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Type5" xml:lang="EN">TestType5</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{7,9}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

My script:

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;

my $in_qfn  = $ARGV[0];
my ($parser, $doc, $root, $out_qfn);
my ($name, $path, $suffix);
my ($documentroot, $complexdoc, $copyelem, $test, $fnd_type, $parent);

my @files = glob "$in_qfn/*.xsd";

foreach my $file (@files) {
   print "###LI### 1 $file\n";
   ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($file);
   $out_qfn = "${name}NoRoot.${suffix}";

   $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
   $doc    = $parser->parse_file($file);
   $root   = $doc->documentElement();

   my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc);
   $xpc->registerNs('xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');

   # Get the RootNode element node and delete it
   foreach $test ($xpc->findnodes("//xsd:element", $root)) {
      $fnd_type = $test->getAttribute('type') or next;

      if ( $xpc->findnodes('./@name[.="RootNode"]', $test) ) {
         foreach my $fnd_node ($xpc->findnodes('./@name[.="RootNode"]', $test)) {
            $fnd_type = $fnd_node->getAttribute('type') or next;
            $parent = $fnd_node->[0]->parentNode;
            $parent->removeChild($fnd_node->[0]);
         }
      }
   }

   # Get the RootNode Complext Type node
   foreach $test ($xpc->findnodes("//xsd:complexType", $root)) {
      if ($xpc->findnodes('./@name[.="RootNode"]', $root)) {
         $complexdoc = $xpc->findnodes('./@name[.="RootNode"]', $root);
         $copyelem = $xpc->findnodes("//xsd:element", $complexdoc);
         # Copy the element node within RootNode node to the top level
         $root->appendChild($copyelem->cloneNode(1));
      }
   }

   $doc->toFile($out_qfn);
}
```

However, the script throws error:

```
Can't locate object method "getAttribute" via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, start with adding `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: Can you post the expected result, too?

Comment: @choroba, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to `findnodes` in *list context* will return a list of matching nodes. That is how your first loop

```
foreach $test ($xpc->findnodes("//xsd:element", $root)) { ... }
```

works, because `for` applies list context to the expression in parentheses

However, your second loop

```
foreach my $fnd_node ($documentroot = $xpc->findnodes('./@name[.="RootNode"]', $test)) { ... }
```

puts `findnodes` into *scalar context* because you first assign the result to `$documentroot`. That causes `findnodes` to return an `XML::LibXML::NodeList` object instead of a list of nodes, and the loop will iterate just once, setting `$fnd_node` to that object and causing the errors you see

I'm unclear why you have added the assignment to `$documentroot`, as it will just set both `$documentroot` and `$fnd_node` to the same value, which hass no advantage. Your errors would go away if you removed that assignment and replaced `$documentroot` with`$fnd_node` in the body of the loop

By the way, there is no need for the test

```
if ( $xpc->findnodes('./@name[.="RootNode"]', $test) ) { ... }
```

before looping over the same call to `findnodes`. If the call finds no matching nodes then the `for` loop won't execute at all

---

#### Update

There were a few other problems with your program. For instance you didn't delete the original `<xs:complexType name="RootNode">` element, and you inserted the contained `<xs:element name="real_node" type="RealNode"/>` at the end of the file

I've fixed your code like this

```perl
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML ();
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext ();
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;

my ($in_qfn) = @ARGV;

my @files = $in_qfn ? glob "$in_qfn/*.xsd" : 'test.xsd';

for my $file ( @files ) {

    print "###LI### 1 $file\n";

    my ( $name, $path, $suffix ) = fileparse( $file, qr/\.[^.]*/ );
    my $out_qfn = "${name}NoRoot${suffix}";

    print "###LO### 1 $out_qfn\n";

    my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
    my $doc    = $parser->parse_file( $file );
    my $root   = $doc->documentElement();

    my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $doc );
    $xpc->registerNs( 'xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' );

    # Get the RootNode element node and delete it
    for my $element_root ( $xpc->findnodes( '//xsd:element[@name="RootNode"]', $root ) ) {
        my $parent = $element_root->parentNode;
        $parent->removeChild( $element_root );
    }

    # Get the RootNode Complex Type node
    for my $complex_root ( $xpc->findnodes( '//xsd:complexType[@name="RootNode"]', $root ) ) {

        my ($copyelem) = $xpc->findnodes( ".//xsd:element", $complex_root );

        # Copy the element node within RootNode node to the top level
        $root->insertBefore(
            $copyelem->cloneNode( 1 ),
            $root->firstChild
        );

        # Put a newline before the cloned copy
        $root->insertBefore(
            XML::LibXML::Text->new( "\n\n    " ),
            $root->firstChild
        );

        # Remove the <xs:complexType name="RootNode">
        $complex_root->parentNode->removeChild($complex_root);
    }

    $doc->toFile( $out_qfn );
}
```

#### output

```xsd
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="real_node" type="RealNode"/>




    <xs:complexType name="RealNode">
            <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">TestName</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Type" xml:lang="EN">TestType</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Elem2" type="Type2" minOccurs="1">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation source="Name3" xml:lang="EN">TestName3</xs:documentation>
                                    <xs:documentation source="Type3" xml:lang="EN">TestType3</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Elem4" type="Type4" maxOccurs="99"/>
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Type2">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{9,9}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Type4">
            <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Name5" xml:lang="EN">TestName5</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation source="Type5" xml:lang="EN">TestType5</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{7,9}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: There is no need to have the result assigned, hence I've modified the script, but the error output is still the same...

Comment: @dellair: No, it isn't "still the same". The message is now `Can't locate object method "getAttribute" via package "XML::LibXML::Attr"`, whereas before it was `via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList"`.

Comment: @dellair: I have fixed the remaining errors and added a functional version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described the logic what elements to remove and replace. The following code just does what you said: replaces one element by another and removes a third one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $dom = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => shift);
my $xpc = 'XML::LibXML::XPathContext'->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs(xsd => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
my $root = $dom->documentElement;

my $replace    = $xpc->findnodes('//xsd:element[@name="RootNode"]');
my $replace_by = $xpc->findnodes('//xsd:element[@name="real_node"]');
my $remove     = $xpc->findnodes('//xsd:complexType[@name="RootNode"]');

die "Can't replace by several" if $replace_by->size > 1;

$_->parentNode->removeChild($_) for @$remove;
$_->replaceNode($replace_by->[0]) for @$replace;

print $dom;
```

Note that `findnodes` returns a nodelist, you can check its size with `->size` as shown in the code, and access it members as elements of an array reference.